# Is the Enterprise crew terrified of Q? If not, should they be?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

Though Q has shown great powers in basically all of his encounters with the Enterprise, the crew of the flagship doesn't seem to show much fear when dealing with him. I realize that they're professionals and everything, but with the exception of Data, shouldn't everyone fear Q, try to avoid him, and certainly not provoke him (yelling at Q, insulting him, etc.)? This is a being that can turn the entire ship into a pretzel in an instant if he so desires. Thus, more awe and even fear seem to be in order, but it oftentimes seems like the exact opposite is seen.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Is the crew of the Enterprise terrified of Q? No. Not really. Not anymore. Should they be? Perhaps, but you can threaten someone with death only so many times without killing them before they stop taking you seriously.

- Indeed, the Enterprise's Captain and later her crew mostly held Q in contempt. While he does indeed have great power, he has also exposed the Enterprise and by proxy, the Federation, to fantastic risk (the Borg, for example) all for his personal amusement.
- He may attempt to mitigate this by claiming it is in the best interests of Humanity, but his manner, technique and bearing makes him an insufferable person under most circumstances.
- It is Q's demeanor toward the crew's efforts (having to work, exploration, living, eating and the other sundry issues of life) which makes them loathe him even more. Q acts as if he is too good to engage in anything resembling work.

- Each encounter with Q became less and less of a threat because he spent more time showing he was less interested in destroying the Enterprise than he was with toying with it. Guinan's attack of Q, during a period of brief mortality, changed the crew's relationship with the enigmatic being (which may have been exactly what she wanted).

Answer (score 1):

The enterprise and Picard specificly does not respond well to intimidation. While Q is one of the most powerful entities in the known galaxy the enterprise crew especially has grown accustomed to his interference, and show little fear towards him. If anything the enterprise crew is rude and treats Q poorly. I think we can attribute this to them seeming to understand that if Q wanted to kill destroy them he could, but hed rather keep them alive to toy with them another game. He doesn't show the crew much of a cruel side. Theoretically they should fear him as he holds the power basically of a God over them. But thats what we like about the enterprise... they don't believe in no win scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Given Q's powers, they ought to have some respect for him. Also, since he dropped them in Borg space, resulting in 18 MIA (presumed assimilated), they probably should fear him at least a little - he could always do worse. On the other hand, if he had a mind to do worse, one would think he'd have done so long before "Encounter at Farpoint". I think they regard him with annoyed suspicion. Sort of "Oh no, not again... just what are you up to now?".

Comment: Interesting. I always thought the eighteen crewmembers had died.

Comment: None of the episode dialog confirms anything about their fate, only that there were 18 persons in the slice extracted by the Borg. We don't know if the Borg tractor beam was able to maintain a breathable atmosphere inside the "sample". Given their propensity for study, adaptation, and assimilating just about any living humanoid, they would be passing up a big opportunity to let the victims die. But yes, perhaps they did die. Either way, lost.

Comment: Well, assimilation wasn't established yet, either. They just wanted the machinery of the Enterprise, not the people. I believe we even saw them apparently reproducing with babies (later assumed to be assimilated infants).